# Trying to send data via Socket to a ZVT Terminal

Tags: php, sockets, hex, 8-bit

How can I send data to a listening Terminal ?!?! (see task)

Szenario is:

I have a terminal that is listening on a IP:PORT e.g. 192.168.1.100:12345

I create a socket and connect like

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);
```

Now I want to write data to the socket. The data i have looks like:

```
0x06 0x01 0x07 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x69
```

actually the terminal should show up `0.69 cent` in the display. But i need to send the data infront of the `0x69` too.

I'm sending the Data like

```
socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));
```

I have read some about a php `pack()` function and tried this...

```
$data = pack( "C", "\x06\x01\x07\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x69" );
```

what i have also tried is

```
$data = pack("c","\x06\x01\x07\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x69");//nothing happens
$data = "0x06 0x01 0x07 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x69";//nothing happens
```

but this doesn't do the thing.

I friend of mine worte a programm in c++ and it works easy.

**TASK**

Task is to send data in 8bit format and as hex.

**EDIT**

**[C++ Code](http://pastebin.com/JDbfCSvd)**

Comment: I would try `pack("c");` (lowercased)

Comment: I have seen applications which expect the data to be sent as a hex string, not binary. meaning you send the string(!) `"0x06 0x01 0x07 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x69"`.. Have you tried this?

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, this was my first try but the terminal just does nothing :) should i provide you with the c++ code ?

Comment: Can you debug the other end? Meaning the target computer? Can you show the C++ program from your friend?

Comment: @hek2mgl i added the c++ code at the bottom of my post

Comment: Having the C++ code, `pack('C')` should work. I would debug the traffic between the C++ program and the target device and compare it to the traffic between PHP and the target

Comment: @hek2mgl so you mean a big `C` ?

Comment: Yes, unsigned char -> `C`

Comment: I suggested: `I would debug the traffic between the C++ program and the target device and compare it to the traffic between PHP and the target` .. Did you followed this?

Comment: actually not. i dont have time at the moment for this. is a task on my work and now its weekend. ill check this next week as soon as i have time for this :)

Comment: I'm with you! now it is weekend :) ..

Answer (score 2):

Your authorization command (06 01): 0x06 0x01 0x07 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x69

is totally correct, your message is 7 bytes long (0x07) and the amount (data block field: 0x04) is 6 byte BCD-packed in Euro-cents with leading zeros (0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x69). One byte is represented with two HEX characters, so the transmitted amount is: 69 Cent. Everything which has to do with the amount display format, is a configuration issue of the terminal itself.

See here for a free version of the zvt protocol

https://www.terminalhersteller.de/pdf/PA00P015_13.08_en.pdf

You can use a lot of programming languages to create a socket connection to a terminal but there are not so many 'full' implementations of the ZVT protocol... which you will need to make the communication complete. I recommend C#, Java or Node.js.  It's also common sense to call the registration command (06 00) when you begin a communication, this includes the config-byte!

Comment: Little late, im do not work there anymore :D but thank you for your answere... may ill need it some day. May ill code a new interface... never know :D

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but maybe it helps somebody:

You can use [hex2bin](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php):

```
$data = "06010704000000000069";
socket_write($socket, hex2bin($data));
```

As mentioned in the answer above, you maybe need to send the REGISTRATION command (0600) first (once).

Comment: 2 years later, still working in the same Company, still having the same problem. So actually it's never to late if there is no solution. :) i do have to rebuild this Szenario and will try this one...  Thank you :D

Comment: still havent tried this. Atm im very busy at work and the priority of some projects are higher so this has to wait :) but be sure, if its tested and it works, of course ill accept this answere :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should sent command 06 00 first, before 06 01?

Comment: is this an answere or a question ?

Comment: this is suggestion. sequence of ZVT commands should start with 06 00

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked well with the following:
`$data = "\x06\x01\x0f\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x69\x19\x40\x06\x04\x40\x02\xff\x00";`